# Hiding/Showing Content Based on Form Select Value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display hidden content using jQuery. The code I am using works great with radio/checkboxes but does not work with select options. The content is hidden when the page loads, but does not display when the associated option is chosen from the select group.

**jQuery**

```
$("#tabText").css("display","none");
$("#tabWebsite").css("display","none");

$("#tabTypeSelect").click(function(){
   if ($('input[name=tabType]:selected').val() == "text" ) {
      $("#tabText").slideDown("fast");
   } 
   else if ($('input[name=tabType]:selected').val() == "url" ) {    
      $("#tabWebsite").slideDown("fast");
   } 
   else {
      $("#tabText").slideUp("fast");
      $("#tabWebsite").slideUp("fast");
   }
});
```

**HTML Form**

```
<select name="tabType" class="form-control" id="tabTypeSelect">
   <option value="text">Text Block</option>
   <option value="url">Website Attachment</option>
</select>
```

**HTML Content To Toggle**

```
<div class="form-group" id="tabText">
    Blah Blah
</div>                                  
<div class="form-group" id="tabWebsite">
    Blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabWebsite").css("display","none");
$("#tabTypeSelect").change(function(){
    if($('select[name=tabType] option:selected').val() == "text" ) {
    $("#tabText").slideDown("fast");
        $("#tabWebsite").slideUp("fast");
    } 
    else {
        $("#tabText").slideUp("fast");
        if($('select[name=tabType] option:selected').val() == "url" ) {    
            $("#tabWebsite").slideDown("fast");
        } else {
        $("#tabWebsite").slideUp("fast");
        }
    } 
});
```

this works